# Use Sphinx to make a bibliography in a latex document

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, bibliography

I am currently using Sphinx to produce a latex document.  I have some problems with the Bibliography.
I would like the Bibliography to appear in the table of contents without a chapter number.

When I include the Bibliography as a separate section, for example using the following reStructured text file:

```
************
Bibliography
************

.. bibliography:: NullFeaturesInQGIS.bib
   :style: plain
```

I end up with a numbered chapter called "Bibliography" and then the actual "Bibliography" two pages later.

[image: Copy of the table of contents from the latex pdf file]

What I would like to achieve is a table of contents heading of "Bibliography" and that to point to the Bibliography without additional empty pages.

Comment: I presume that you use the sphinxcontrib-bibtex extension. What happens if you simply remove the `Bibliography` section heading?

Comment: If I remove the Bibliography section heading I still get two empty pages, and, I don't get any  Table of Contents.

Comment: For a temporary solution I have separate index.rst files for html and latex output from Sphinx.  Within the index.rst file for html I include a Bibliography section with a bibliography directive in the toctree (table of contents), in the index.rst file for latex I have removed both the Bibliography section and the bibliography directive.  This gives me the result that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different approaches are shown below that creates a Bibliography section in both the *html* and *latex* outputs from Sphinx.

**1. Using two distinct "index" restructured text files**

One approach that creates a Bibliography section in both the Sphinx *html* and *latex* outputs uses two **index** restructured text files.

For the *html* output, the `index.rst` file should be like:

```
===============
Project Heading
===============

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   section_1
   section_2
   section_3
   bibliography
```

For the *latex* output, the `index_latex.rst` file should be like:

```
===============
Project Heading
===============

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   section_1
   section_2
   section_3
```

The `bibliography.rst` file should be like:

```
************
Bibliography
************

.. bibliography:: bibtex_filename.bib
   :style: plain
```

Within the Sphinx configuration file (e.g. `conf.py`), you need to distinguish between the two different index files.  For example:

```
# The html index document.
master_doc = 'index'

# The latex index document
latex_doc = 'index_latex'
```

**2. Using one `index.rst` file and using the `.. raw::` directive**

What follows was adapted from https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4775.  This approach uses the same `index.rst` file for both *html* and *latex* outputs.  The `index.rst` file should be the same as shown for *html* output above, and, should include a reference to the `bibliography.rst` file.  The, `bibliography.rst` file needs to have the `.. raw::` directive at the beginning:

```
.. raw:: latex

   \cleardoublepage
   \begingroup
   \renewcommand\chapter[1]{\endgroup}
   \phantomsection

************
Bibliography
************

.. bibliography:: bibtex_filename.bib
   :style: plain
```

**NOTE**

Using the Sphinx `.. only::` directive with a single `index.rst` file, like shown below **DOES NOT WORK**.  Specifically, the *latex* document will be missing content.  This is possibly due to [problems with the `.. only::` directive.](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2150)

```
===============
Project Heading
===============

.. only:: html

   .. toctree::
      :maxdepth: 2
      :caption: Contents:

      section_1
      section_2
      section_3
      bibliography

.. only:: latex

   .. toctree::
      :maxdepth: 2
      :caption: Contents:

      section_1
      section_2
      section_3
```

Comment: maybe this [hack](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4775#issuecomment-375906390) using raw latex, suitably adapted, could avoid two separated index.rst files (untested)

Comment: Thanks jfbu, it tested the hack that you referenced and it works without error.  I have now included it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Sphinx .. only:: directive in the bibliography.rst file like this:

```
.. only:: html

    ************
    Bibliography
    ************

.. bibliography:: bibtex_filename.bib
   :style: plain
```

and keeping one index.rst file like this:

```
===============
Project Heading
===============

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   section_1
   section_2
   section_3
   bibliography
```

solved it for me.